# Complex measure

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

I found the following statement in one of my books.

*Suppose $\varphi$ is a continuous function on the compact subset of $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then
$$f\mapsto\int f(x)\varphi(x)dx$$
defines a complex measure on X. A common notation for this measure would be $\varphi dx$.*

How to understand "defines a measure" - how a mapping between $f$ and the integral can define the measure? What would be the measure in this case? $\mu(x)=\varphi(x)dx$ ?

Comment: This looks like a function that takes functions to real numbers. A measure should take sets to real numbers.

Comment: Have a look at the [Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz–Markov–Kakutani_representation_theorem) (commonly attributed to Riesz alone).

Comment: @DanielXiang, yes, the initial notion of "measure" is non-negative, real-valued, (possibly allowing $+\infty$ as a value), but we can also have complex-valued measures (now disallowing $+\infty$, because the arithmetic won't work), and eventually "projection-valued measures" in operator theory. For the integral map on functions to be complex-linear, we may as well have a complex-valued measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of a "measure" as a set-function, then the measure $\mu$ defined here is
$$
\mu(E) = \int_E \varphi(x)\,dx
$$
for Borel sets $E \subseteq X$.

That is: for this measure we have
$$
\int_X f \,d\mu = \int_X f(x)\varphi(x)\,dx
$$

On the other hand, if you follow Boubaki, then a "measure" is a linear functional, and
$$
f\mapsto\int f(x)\varphi(x)dx
$$
is a complex measure.

Comment: Can you tell me in which Bourbaki book I can read more about it?

Comment: You can begin with Boubaki's volume *Intégation*.  https://www.amazon.com/Intégration-Chapitres-French-N-Bourbaki/dp/3540353283/